# Ruby-readability gem encoding

Tags: ruby, encoding, readability

When I use the [ruby-readability](https://github.com/iterationlabs/ruby-readability) gem, characters, which were originally inside the links are displayed in wrong encoding.
The problem occurs if the page in utf-8 charset, and contains no-latin characters. At the same time on the local machine everything works fine, although the system locale and version of Ruby on the server and on the local machine is the same.
I did not found any code in the ruby-readability sources, because of which this may occurs. who knows what the problem is? or maybe someone knows replacement to this gem? sorry for my bad english

Comment: I'm not quite sure how difficult the source code is, but have you tried looking into the source yourself to fix it?

Comment: Yes, but have not found anything that can affect on it.
may be it related with some environment settings.

Comment: I've found the same problem. Have you figured out any solutions yet?